# Understanding function pointer declaration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have to describe the following code:

```
    char *(**f[][]) ();
```

I understand the "char *" at the beginning and the "()" at the end: It's a function which doesn't have arguments and returns a pointer to char. But what does " ( * * f [ ][ ]  ) " mean?

Can anyone help me please? Thanks =D

Comment: It's not a function which doesn't have arguments, but a function whose arguments are not specified. A function with no arguments has `void` between the `()`s.

Answer (score 6):

There's a very useful website you might want to know about: http://cdecl.org/

> declare f as array of array of pointer to pointer to function returning pointer to char

In a bit easier to read english, `f` is a 2d array of pointers to function pointers, that return strings (or pointers to characters).

Quite why you'd need that I have no idea.